# How to get a count of all instances of a foreign key in a different model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model A and model B. Model B has a member foreign key of model A. I wish to keep try of the number of B's attached to model A. I would also like

In model A we are trying to use and update the number off instances of B to A and hold that in model A
`num_B = models.IntegerField(default=0)`

In model B we have the member ForeignKey
`modelAInstance = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In model A we are trying to use and update the number of instances of `B` to `A` and hold that in model `A`.

Please do *not* do that. This is a form of data duplication, and it is quite hard to keep data in sync. Even if it is stored in the same database on the same server. It would require making correct updates each time you *add* a `B` object, *remove* `B`  object, and *change* the `A` of a `B` object. To make matters even worse if another application can alter the database (for example a database administrator), that could still get the data out of sync.

Usually it is better to [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset of `A` objects, so if the model looks like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

you can obtain a `QuerySet` of `A` objects with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

A.objects.annotate(
    num_b=Count('b')
)
```

The `A` objects that arise form *this* `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.num_b` with the number of *related* `B` objects.

Comment: Is there a way to get the count of all objects with the foreign key? Or would I need to loop through the database to find it? Edit: I should also ask what is the best way to retrieve the foreign key data?

Comment: @Thothen: well this does it, as said, the annotation will add an extra field, it will do so in bulk to avoid extra roundtrips to the database.

Comment: would the annotate call go in the `models.py`? I am confused as to where I would include your example in my project, becuase we should only have to call this once correct?

Comment: @Thothen: normally in views where you need it, or in the `queryset` in class-based views, and the `ModelViewSet` in the Django REST framework.